# FInd the Mean of prices from the database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get the mean of the prices but when I display them I don't know how to add them up. Here is my code. I want to find the mean, but I can't. The prices in the database are stored like this: `$12.00` so I guess I will have to find and replace the `$` sign.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `o_state`='NJ' and `d_state`='CA'";

$run = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){

$a = $rows['pay'];

echo "$a+$a";

}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the datatype of the `pay` column is varchar, and not float?

Comment: Prices shouldn't be stored like that. You're going to have to strip out the `$` on your end.

Comment: yes  i got it from a csv file like that so it had the $ include. Should it be change?

Comment: Parse it to a numeric value. Preferably decimal.

Comment: @youngkid7 it would probably be best if you do change that column if it is going to hold float values

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the mean from the database using SQL, if you can get the data in numeric format:

```
SELECT AVG(pay) from `TABLE 1` WHERE `o_state`='NJ' and `d_state`='CA'
```

This would be the most efficient as the Database does not have to return the entire result set to PHP.

If cannot and you have to do it yourself you could:

```
$run = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$a = 0;
$count = 0;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){

     $a += preg_replace('/\$/', '', $rows['pay']);
     $count++;

} 
$avg = $a / $count;
echo "Average: $avg";
```